# Is it needed enable the soap in my server?

Tags: soap

I am getting this error from eway token payment API,

"soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

And In my server there is no soap enable.

Is it the problem or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request." means your server is not receving SOAP data

I think your server don't have SOAP installed. Try installing the SOAP

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I will try to enable the SOAP. Thanks